# Error creating FK Constraint: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Period' that match the referencing column

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Majority of the tables in my database consist of composite primary keys due to the locations being different on the original platform but the identities are only unique at the given location. I have a `Period` table for the start and end dates of our fiscal year separated by the `FiscalYear` and `PeriodID`. `PeriodID` is repeating 1-12 so the primary key for this table is both the `FiscalYear` and `PeriodID`

```
FiscalYear INT NOT NULL,
PeriodID TINYINT NOT NULL,
PeriodStart DATE NOT NULL,
PeriodEnd DATE NOT NULL,
PeriodWeeks TINYINT NOT NULL,
QuarterID TINYINT NOT NULL,
DateManipulate DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Period] PRIMARY KEY (PeriodID, FiscalYear)
```

I also have a `Clinic.Dates` table that uses the same `FiscalYear` and `PeriodID` but has data unique to each location. I have these separated so I don't have 40 instances of the same `FiscalYear` and `PeriodID` with the date ranges being repeated.

```
ClinicID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_ClinicDates] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Clinic.Master(ClinicID),
FiscalYear INT NOT NULL,
PeriodID TINYINT NOT NULL,
PeriodDays INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Dates] PRIMARY KEY (ClinicID, PeriodID, FiscalYear)
```

The issue I am having is creating a foreign key constraint between these tables due to the columns not being unique on their own.

```
ALTER TABLE Clinic.Dates ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PeriodDates FOREIGN KEY(FiscalYear, PeriodID) REFERENCES Clinic.Period(FiscalYear, PeriodID)
GO
```

The error I'm getting is:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Clinic.Period' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_PeriodDates'.

My question: is there another way around this? The primary key exists in the `Clinic.Period` table but isn't recognized when attempting to make this FK constraint.

UPDATE: Here are a couple of data examples for both of the tables for a better perspective.

Period Table:
[image]

Clinic.Dates Table:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the reference backwards.  It should go from the `Clinic.Periods` table *to* `Clinic.Dates`:

```
ALTER TABLE Clinic.Periods ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PeriodDates FOREIGN KEY(FiscalYear, PeriodID) REFERENCES Clinic.Dates(FiscalYear, PeriodID)
GO
```

Comment: I don't believe so, the `Clinic.Dates` table is going to have multiple instances of `FiscalYear` and `PeriodID` so it couldn't be used on it's own for the constraint. Regardless I gave it a shot and received the same error: `There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Clinic.Dates' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_PeriodDates'.`